# GETX moves to home screen on wrong login

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

Hello I have a problem here am a beginner on dart and flutter development and now I stuck here, I have Auth file and login file now the problem is when ever I put credentials even wrong credentials the app still takes me to homepage what am I doing Wrong, here is my code!

```
import 'package:adlisting/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:adlisting/services/Config.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
// ignore: unnecessary_import
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/get_state_manager.dart';

class Auth extends GetxController {
  login(email, password) {
    var url = Uri.parse(Constants().apiUrl + "/auth/login");
    var input = json.encode({
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    });
    http
        .post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: input)
        .then((res) {
      print(res);
      print(res.body);
      Get.offAll(() => HomeScreen());
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving condition as - if the response status code is 200 it should move to the homepage else , if the status code is different give it a toast saying wrong credentials

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the response of API first you have to check API is giving 200 response or not like this

```
class Auth extends GetxController {
  login(email, password) {
    var url = Uri.parse(Constants().apiUrl + "/auth/login");
    var input = json.encode({
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    });
    http
        .post(
      url,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: input,
    )
        .then((res) {
      print(res);
      print(res.body);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          //this means API is working fine
          Get.offAll(() => HomeScreen());
      } else {
         //show some error
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
}
```

now, in 200 response you have to check the success status of API which will be returning from backend like this

```
{
'success':true or false
}
```

**note: Its not same for all APIs, it can vary API to API you can ask your backend developer**

```
class Auth extends GetxController {
  login(email, password) {
    var url = Uri.parse(Constants().apiUrl + "/auth/login");
    var input = json.encode({
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    });
    http
        .post(
      url,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: input,
    )
        .then((res) {
      print(res);
      print(res.body);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
         //this means API is working fine
        if (res.body['success'] == true) {
          Get.offAll(() => HomeScreen());
        } else {
          print("username or password is not correct");
        }
      } else {
        //show some error
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much brother, this worked like a charm after getting response the status showed that I was using get command instead of POST command thank you so much bro @ahmad hassan